# Results not being grouped when using GROUP BY on UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables: `Ambulances` and `Responders`. The `Responder` table has one `call_sign` column and the `Ambulances` table has 4 columns - `call_sign_1, call_sign_2, call_sign_3, call_sign_4`.

I want to write a query to list every call_sign and how many times it appears in the database (i.e. how many calls each responder has attended - including the ones in ambulances). The query I've created displays some call_sign's more than once.

I'd like them to be grouped so each call_sign only appears once.

```
SELECT * FROM (
select call_sign as call_sign, count(call_sign) as `call_sign_count` from responders group by call_sign
UNION ALL
select call_sign_1 as call_sign, count(call_sign_1) as `call_sign_count` from ambulances group by call_sign
UNION ALL
select call_sign_2 as call_sign, count(call_sign_2) as `call_sign_count` from ambulances group by call_sign
UNION ALL
select call_sign_3 as call_sign, count(call_sign_3) as `call_sign_count` from ambulances group by call_sign
UNION ALL
select call_sign_4 as call_sign, count(call_sign_4) as `call_sign_count` from ambulances group by call_sign
) 
a WHERE call_sign IS NOT NULL Group By call_sign, call_sign_count
```

The databse and query can be found in this fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9grxeiA277KtUqsiUbYMA8/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it displays the same `call_sign` multiple times because in the outer query you group by on `call_sign` **and** `call_sign_count`. If you want each `call_sign` to appear only once, then you can only group on that field and use an aggregate function on `call_sign_count`, let's say sum().

```
SELECT call_sign, sum(call_sign_count) total_call_sign_count FROM (
select call_sign as call_sign, count(call_sign) as `call_sign_count` from responders group by call_sign
UNION ALL
select call_sign_1 as call_sign, count(call_sign_1) as `call_sign_count` from ambulances group by call_sign
UNION ALL
select call_sign_2 as call_sign, count(call_sign_2) as `call_sign_count` from ambulances group by call_sign
UNION ALL
select call_sign_3 as call_sign, count(call_sign_3) as `call_sign_count` from ambulances group by call_sign
UNION ALL
select call_sign_4 as call_sign, count(call_sign_4) as `call_sign_count` from ambulances group by call_sign
) 
a WHERE call_sign IS NOT NULL Group By call_sign
```